# Get set with smallest 3rd value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have an array. This iterator-object including multiple tuples of length 3. I would like to pick a tuple with the smallest third value.

for example (I just wrote it down as a list but it's not a list)

`a = [(1, 5, 4), (2, 5, 0.4), (3, 4, 0.4), (1, 9, 0.3)]`

the output should be:

`(1, 9, 0.3)`

Comment: Please include what you've tried and let us know why it's not working.

Comment: I used this function https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_prediction.jaccard_coefficient.html and want to get the pair with the smallest result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min` with a custom key fetching the 3rd value

```
values = [(1, 5, 4), (2, 5, 0.4), (3, 4, 0.4), (1, 9, 0.3)]

min_tuple = min(values, key=lambda x: x[2])
print(min_tuple)  # (1, 9, 0.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do an algorithm with linear complexity that will iterate in the in the array and find the smallest using the
**min** function

and convert into tuple

### Code:

```
def smallest(a):
    result = []
    for x in a:
        result.append(min(x))
    return result
a=[(1, 5, 4), (2, 5, 0.4), (3, 4, 0.4), (1, 9, 0.3)]
print(smallest(a)) #(1, 9, 0.3)
```

Comment: is this going to be faster than just using the min-function on the Iterator?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import functools
a = [(1, 5, 4), (2, 5, 0.4), (3, 4, 0.4), (1, 9, 0.3)]
print(functools.reduce(lambda c, m: m if m[2] < c[2] else c, a))
```